# Poetry install error while running it on github workflow

Tags: python, django, github-actions, python-poetry

Encountering an error message while installing dependencies using Poetry with GitHub Actions. It works fine when I install it locally. However, it gives out the runtime error of ['Key "files" does not exist.'] missing when Action runs on GitHub for the line [Install dependencies].

Poetry Lock file URL
https://pastebin.com/nmLmpYLh

**Error Message**

```
4s
Run poetry install
Creating virtualenv ailyssa-backend in /home/runner/work/ailyssa_backend/ailyssa_backend/.venv
Installing dependencies from lock file

[NonExistentKey]
'Key "files" does not exist.'
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

**Github Workflow**

```
name: Linting

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]
    types: [opened, synchronize]

jobs:
  linting:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: [3.9]
        os: [ubuntu-latest]
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}

    - name: Set up Poetry
      uses: abatilo/actions-poetry@v2.0.0

    - name: Install dependencies
      run:  poetry install

    - name: Run code quality check
      run:  poetry run pre-commit run -a
```

**Toml File**

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "ailyssa_backend"
version = "4.0.9"
description = "The RESTful API for Ailytics using the Django Rest Framework"
authors = ["Shan Tharanga <63629580+ShanWeera@users.noreply.github.com>"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
Django = "4.1.3"
djangorestframework = "^3.13.1"
django-environ = "^0.8.1"
djangorestframework-simplejwt = "^5.0.0"
drf-spectacular = {version = "0.25.1", extras = ["sidecar"]}
django-cors-headers = "^3.10.0"
uvicorn = "^0.16.0"
django-filter = "^21.1"
psycopg2 = "^2.9.3"
django-auditlog = "2.2.1"
boto3 = "^1.22.4"
django-allow-cidr = "^0.4.0"
pyppeteer = "^1.0.2"
plotly = "^5.8.1"
pandas = "^1.4.2"
psutil = "^5.9.1"
requests = "^2.28.0"
opencv-python = "^4.6.0"
tzdata = "^2022.1"
pyotp = "^2.6.0"
channels = "3.0.5"
dictdiffer = "^0.9.0"
deepmerge = "^1.0.1"
django-oauth-toolkit = "^2.1.0"
drf-writable-nested = "^0.7.0"
Twisted = {version = "22.10.0", extras = ["tls,http2"]}
pathvalidate = "^2.5.2"
humanize = "^4.4.0"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pre-commit = "^2.15.0"
mypy = "^0.971"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"

[tool.poetry.scripts]
manage = 'manage:main'

[tool.black]
line-length = 120
skip-string-normalization = true
target-version = ['py38']
include = '''
/(
    \.pyi?$
  | \.pyt?$
)/
'''
exclude = '''
/(
    \.eggs
  | \.git
  | \.hg
  | \.mypy_cache
  | \.tox
  | \.venv
  | _build
  | buck-out
  | build
  | dist
  | tests/.*/setup.py
)/
'''
```

Comment: Add lock file please

Comment: We need more context about the error message. At what step did it occur exactly? You should copy-paste the whole log trace of this particular step. (I do not think the lock file is necessary).

Comment: @OleksandrSpazhev Here is the lock file https://pastebin.com/nmLmpYLh

Comment: @sinoroc I have added the log trace

Comment: Maybe retry with more verbose output, because this error message does not have enough details. -- One possibility is that one entry in the lock file is missing a `files` field. So maybe the lock file needs to be re-generated. -- Hard to tell.

Comment: @RohitSthapit, agree with sinoroc. Try to regenerate lock file